# Cargar código en un void Load para el form C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

¡Buen día!

Tengo un trozo de código en un botón, que va contando actualizaciones y borrados de la base de datos. Para insertar se abre un nuevo *form*, y cuando se inserta regresa al *form* principal.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que a la hora de regresar del *form* de insertar al principal se me actualice automáticamente (sin darle *click* al botón)?

Adjunto código, gracias.

```
private void LoadCounters()
{
    // get contact counters for current login
    var dic = DaoWaybill.GetReceiverInformation(Constants.strIdUser, Constants.strUsername);
    lblGuides.Text = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "guides").Value;

    lblContactIncident.Text = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "total_incident").Value;
    lblContactConfirmed.Text = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "total_confirmed").Value;
}
```

Código actual del botón (evento *Click*):

```
private void radButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadCounters();
}
```

Comment: En donde llamas al nuevo form? que se ejecuta al volver? cuando es que vuelves? podrias levantar tranquilamente un evento al volver...

Comment: A la hora de buscar el ID, se despiega un DataSet, al dar click en la linea del usuario abre el nuevo form, cuando vuelve no ejecuta nada, para lelvar el contador tienes que darle al botón radButton2_Click() y funciona.

Comment: no apretes el boton.. hace que el otro form levante un evento y que ese evento sea lo que pasa al apretar tu boton ;)

Comment: Exacto gbianchi, eso quiero hacer, pero no sé cómo puedo hacer el evento, ¿Tienes alguna idea de como?

Comment: vamos al principio.. no sabes escribir un evento? no sabes como conectarte con un evento? que es lo que no sabes? tambien, podrias conectar los dos formularios para llamar a un metodo del formulario padre desde el hijo antes de cerrarlo.. y luego cerrarlo...

Comment: Aparte de generar un evento, una alternativa interesante, puede ser pasar la acción de actualizar contadores al constructor del _form_ secundario, y que cuando este haga el cambio correspondiente, o justo antes de salir del _form_, se ejecute esa acción.

Comment: Las 2 primeras son correctas, ejemplo, lo de conectar dos formularios para llamar al padre desde el hijo no sé cómo hacerlo, lo que necesito es que al cerrar el hijo, el padre se "Refresque" con el void LoadCounters();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenta [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi), puedes "conectar" dos formularios para que el secundario acceda a métodos del principal cuando sea necesario.

Esto lo puedes conseguir pasando el formulario principal al constructor del formulario secundario.

```
public class FormularioPrincipal : Form
{
    ...

    public void LoadCounters() { ... }

    public void botonAbrirFormularioSecundario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormularioSecundario secundario = new FormularioSecundario(this);
        ...
    }
}

public class FormularioSecundario : Form
{
    private FormularioPrincipal formularioPrincipal;

    public FormularioSecundario(FormularioPrincipal formularioPrincipal)
    {
        this.formularioPrincipal = formularioPrincipal;
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void metodo()
    {
        ...
        formularioPrincipal.LoadCounters();
    }
}
```

Este enfoque en ocasiones obliga a que métodos internos de un formulario, o propiedades, tengan que ser públicos, para ser accesibles desde el formulario secundario.

Una alternativa algo más selectiva podría ser pasar la propia acción de refrescar los contadores al constructor del formulario secundario.

```
public class FormularioPrincipal : Form
{
    ...

    private void LoadCounters() { ... }

    public void botonAbrirFormularioSecundario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormularioSecundario secundario = new FormularioSecundario(() => LoadCounters());
        ...
    }
}

public class FormularioSecundario : Form
{
    private Action refrescarContadores;

    public FormularioSecundario(Action refrescarContadores)
    {
        this.refrescarContadores = refrescarContadores;
    }

    public void metodo()
    {
        ...
        refrescarContadores?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para aclarar que el método `button_Click` no se correspondía con el botón de refrescar, sino con el elemento visual (que asumo que es un botón), que abre el segundo formulario. En los dos ejemplos he supuesto que el botón de refrescar ya no existe.

Comment: Mi respuesta va en el sentido que dices. En donde quieras que se ejecute la actualización invocas a la acción pasada al constructor. Por lo que el botón de refrescar anterior lo puedes quitar. Simplemente dentro del código del botón _Actualizar_ haces `accionRefrescar?.Invoke();`

Comment: En cualquier caso, si has probado mi respuesta y no funciona puedes abrir una nueva pregunta o bien editar tu pregunta original, para ver qué error puede haber.